# NX: the equivalent of "lerna exec -- yarn link"

Tags: nx-monorepo

Right now I have these two scripts that depend on lerna to link/unlink all packages on a monorepo (yarn classic being used as package manager).

```
    "link:all": "nx exec -- yarn link",
    "unlink:all": "lerna exec -- yarn unlink",
```

Is there a way to do it with `nx` instead?
Running `nx exec -- yarn link` gives me this error:

```
 NX   Unable to determine project name for `nx exec`
```

Comment: According to the [docs][1], what you have is supported. Can you include any additional information on your configuration?



  [1]: https://nx.dev/nx-api/nx/documents/exec